Car stopped on side of road, passengers threatened with being shot if they try to get out of the car or call for help
So I only remember seeing the trailer for this movie, it was fairly new, definitely in the 2000s most like 2010 or later. 
In the trailer this family or friends is driving along a road when something happens. They stop for some reason, either their car breaks down or someone stops them I'm not sure. There is a forest on one side of the road and it turns out that there is a gunman or sniper of some kind hiding in there. 
He threatens to shoot the people in the car if they get out or if they try to make any calls on their cell phones. 
That's all I can remember.. I'm pretty sure it's a thriller. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! I've edited your question title to make it more useful. If you feel I have misunderstood you, please feel free to [edit] it yourself. In future, please make sure your title is descriptive and that it accurately represents your question. Can you clarify... have you only seen the trailer and not the film itself?

Yes only the trailer

Sounds like the thriller Roadside from 2013. From Rotten Tomatoes:

Dan and Mindy Summers are on a road trip along a desolate mountain highway when Dan is forced to exit the SUV to remove a dead tree blocking their path. Before he can get back inside, he and Mindy find themselves held hostage on the side of the road, trapped in their car by a mysterious gunman.

Pretty much everything you've described is in the trailer:




Yes Walt that is it!! Thank you so much it was driving me crazy. I'm new to this website but if there is any way to choose your answer as the best or if you can get points or anything I will do it!

@Slipslide998 Simply click on the check mark next to the answer to approve it. Glad you found it!
